# Node.js vhost as user

Tags: node.js, express, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

Very simply, I'm currently using Express's vhost method to route requests to the appropriate script given a domain name. I really like this route since it means I don't need to have separate ports being listened to by separate node.js instances for each virtual host script and I also don't need a process for each virtual host. However, there is a glaring flaw for me using this method. By using this method, anything in the vhost server has root privileges and not merely the privileges of the user whose script it is. I need know find some way of sandboxing or otherwise running the vhost server as the user that it belongs too. Needless to say, I can't have lower privileged users on the server with access to the root.

TL;DR, What method exists by which I can route requests to different domain name's associated apps without the need to designate ports of which the app would need to know and still disable the author of that script from having access beyond their own user account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my apps, I use [Bouncy](http://npmjs.org/package/bouncy):

```
var bouncy = require( "bouncy" );

var server = bouncy(function( req, res, bounce ) {
    var port;
    var subdomain = req.headers.host.split( "." )[ 0 ];

    switch ( subdomain ) {
        case "xyz":
            port = 4002;
            break;

        default:
            port = 4001;
            break;
    }

    bounce( port );
});

server.listen( 4000 );
```

This way, you may have various apps listening on different ports and on different processes. They all will be proxied to work under the port 4000 aswell, so:

```
xyz.localhost:4002 = xyz.localhost:4000
localhost:4001 = localhost:4000
```

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: Thank you for your time in trying to answer my question. My concern with this approach is that every app will have it's own port and thus the app will need to be listening on the port for requests. Such as for "xyz" subdomain the a server instance needs to be listening on the port, right? I don't know how an author would be able to determine the port programatically chosen for their app.

Comment: I currently have 3 HTTP servers in the same app, in the same process. The app has some config which determine the port of each process. This way it's not too DRY, and I have these servers because of: RESTful API, CDN and general HTML serving. Also, how much servers you'll be running?